# How to calculate Precision, Recall and F-score using python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

The labelTrainData.csv is used to train the classifier for predicting sentiments of Testdata.csv. Finally i got BagOfCentroids.csv.

**labelTrainData.csv**

```
id   sentiment    Tweet
1    0            tweet_1
2    1            tweet_2
3    0            tweet_3
```

**Testdata.csv**

```
id      Tweet
1       tweet_1
2       tweet_2
3       tweet_3
```

**BagOfCentroids.csv**

```
id      sentiment
1       0
2       1
3       1
```

To calculate above metrics, I am trying this,

```
print 'Sentiment precision:'

nltk.metrics.precision(BagOfCentroids['sentiment'], Testdata['sentiment'])

print 'sentiment recall:'

nltk.metrics.recall(BagOfCentroids['sentiment'], Testdata['sentiment'])

print 'sentiment F-measure:'

nltk.metrics.f_measure(BagOfCentroids['sentiment'], Testdata['sentiment'])
```

Is there any way to calculate Precision, Recall and F-score?

Comment: what's the question? Specify what you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far, we can't help ypu otherwise

Comment: @AdamJaamour question edited

Comment: And what happens when you try this?

Comment: @lenz I got this error AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'precision'

Comment: And you found `nltk.metrics.precision` in the documentation, or you came up with that yourself? Maybe you should [have a look at the docs](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics.scores)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this article will be helpful:

[TEXT CLASSIFICATION FOR SENTIMENT ANALYSIS – PRECISION AND RECALL](https://streamhacker.com/2010/05/17/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-precision-recall/)

[Detail about nltk.metrics package](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html#module-nltk.metrics.scores)

This might be because of some import issue